# How to refer to the index field of pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
    payment_method_id   payment_plan_days   plan_list_price actual_amount_paid date
msno                                
YyO+tlZtAXYXoZhNr3Vg3+dfVQvrBVGO8j1mfqe4ZHc=    41  30  129 129 2015-01-01
AZtu6Wl0gPojrEQYB8Q3vBSmE2wnZ3hi1FbK1rQQ0A4=    41  30  149 149 2015-01-01
UkDFI97Qb6+s2LWcijVVv4rMAsORbVDT2wNXF0aVbns=    41  30  129 129 2015-01-02
```

The key is "msno", I need to find out whether majority of "msno" are only using one payment_method_id in different date.

So I tried to group by "msno", "payment_method_id", using

```
 transactions.groupby(['msno', 'payment_method_id']).count()
```

but got error: KeyError: 'msno'

group by using other fields work fine, eg:

```
 transactions.groupby(['payment_plan_days', 'payment_method_id']).count()
```

Then for the `msno`, i can even using `groupby level=0`

```
 transactions.groupby(level=0)
```

But I can't group two levels which includes the first column.

This is what it looks in `transactions.columns`

`Index(['payment_method_id', 'payment_plan_days', 'plan_list_price',
       'actual_amount_paid', 'date']
      dtype='object')`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert index to column, because your pandas version is bellow [`0.20.1`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-enhancements):

> Strings passed to **DataFrame.groupby()** as the **by** parameter may now reference either column names or index level names. Previously, only column names could be referenced. This allows to easily group by a column and index level at the same time.

```
transactions.reset_index().groupby(['msno', 'payment_method_id']).count()
```

So after upgrade your code should work fine:

```
transactions.groupby(['msno', 'payment_method_id']).count()
```

Notice:

Difference between [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) and [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) is `count` omit `NaN`s and `size` not.